# asp.net public string is not a valid identifier

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Very new to asp.net, so new I just installed the IDE! So please be kind.

I am a java developer who needs to create restful web services in asp.net. To start off I wanted to follow this tutorial;

http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api#Exercise1

Having problems when I put in a method into my controller.vb

```
public string[] get()
```

It doesnt seem to like the word string. Says its not a valid identifier. Am I missing something? Possibly have IDE configured wrong?

Comment: Well you say `controller.vb` but you are using a C# tutorial. The brackets after `get` mean it will be a method, is that what you want?

Comment: You have this tagged as C#, but it looks like your file is a VB file. Your file should have a .cs extension.

Comment: where are your method brackets?  `public string[] get(){}`

Comment: add a new project, make sure you select the **MVC 4 C#** project (as is selected in your image).  Then delete that one

Comment: vb would be `Public get() as String()... End Get ' on new line`

Comment: ooooooooo I was under visual basic when I went to create the project....This happenes every time I try and write C#. Creating the correct project type will probably solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# version of what you are trying to do is this:

```
public string[] Get()
{
    return new string[]
    {
         "Hello",
         "World"
    };
}
```

The VB.NET version of the same logic is this:

```
Public Function [Get]() As String()
    Return New String() {"Hello", "World"}
End Function
```

Note: VB.NET uses parentheses `(` and `)` for array indices, while C# uses square brackets `[` and `]`.

Also, `Get` is a poor choice for a method name in VB.NET, as it is a reserved word; thus the brackets around the method name above. Read [Visual Basic Language Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trying to return a method so you would need to add `{}` to the end, otherwise it is expecting a name for the property so something like `public string[] propertyName get() {}`

This is going off C# as that is what you tagged the question ass